# How to keep a self join of a table updated on update of the main table?

Tags: mysql

I have an update statement with a self join shown in the code below. Am supposed to get values from updated columns but I notice that the update on a1 does not reflect on joined a2.

```
UPDATE test.cashbook a1 
inner join test.cashbook a2 on a2.id = (CASE WHEN a1.id>1 then a1.id-1 
END)
SET a1.balanceBroughtFoward = a2.balanceCarriedDown, 
    a1.totalCash = a2.balanceCarriedDown + ifnull(a1.cashSale, 0), 
    a1.balanceCarriedDown = ifnull(a1.totalCash, 0) -(ifnull(a1.Lodgement, 0) + ifnull(a1.Expenses, 0))
    where a1.id > 1
```

The result I expect is to have the previous row's `balanceCarriedFoward` as my current row `balanceBroughtFoward`.

This perhaps is the need for the self join to same table as `a2` but because only the first row (`a1.id = 1`) has a `balancecarriedFoward` before the join, therefore only row two of `a1` is updated though on subsequent rows of the original table (`a1`) the update command updates `balanceCarriedFoward` during the update but I guess this values are not reflected in the self joined table (`a2`) therefore giving null values for `a1.balancbroughtFoward` where row is > 2.

How can I get around this since I am limited to using MySQL 5.6?

Comment: Have you tried this query with `SELECT`?

Comment: Yes, but I can't select from the target table for update which is `a1` as `a2` wouldn't have the updated values. Another approach would have been to put the join in the select from `a2` but mysql doesn't accept join after set clause but rather after update clause.

Comment: I'm sorry @Ikem Chinonso, could you please run this query and post the result here? `SELECT a1.balanceBroughtFoward,a2.balanceCarriedDown,
a1.totalCash,a2.balanceCarriedDown+IFNULL(a1.cashSale, 0),
a1.balanceCarriedDown,IFNULL(a1.totalCash, 0) -(IFNULL(a1.Lodgement, 0) + IFNULL(a1.Expenses, 0))
FROM test.cashbook a1 
INNER JOIN test.cashbook a2 ON a2.id=(CASE WHEN a1.id>1 THEN a1.id-1 END) WHERE a1.id > 1;` . Thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: Thanks @tcadidot0 I was able to achieve what I wanted with the use of variables. I'll post the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a variable to achieve the need of joining `a2` to `a1`. Code below.

`SET bc:= 0
UPDATE test.cashbook
Set balanceBroughtFoward = bc, balanceCarriedFoward = (bc:= totalCash - (Lodgement + Expenses) )`

The above code worked but then I now want to put the update statement in a trigger. it gives syntax error when I try. Am stock at this point.